# fitting curve: which model to describe distribution in weighted knowledge graphs

Tags: python, neural-network, wolfram-mathematica, entropy, model-fitting

As a simple model to represent a knowledge network and learn about properties of weighted graphs, I computed the cosine similarity between Wikipedia articles.

I am looking now at the distribution of the similarity weights for each article (see pictures ).

In the pictures, you see that the curve changes derivative around a certain value (maybe from an exponential, to linear) : I would like to fit the curve and extract that value, where the derivate visibly (or expectedly) change, so that I can divide similar articles in two sets: the "most similar" (left side of the threshold) and the "others" (right side of the threshold).

I want to fit the curve for each article distribution; compare the distribution respect to the mean distribution of all the articles; compare the distribution respect to the distribution of a random weighted network.
(You're suggestions are most welcome in defining working procedure: you know I would like to use this model as a toy model to then train how a network, or an article, may evolve in time).

My background is User Experience with a twist for data science, I wish to comprehend better which model may describe the distribution of values I observed, a proper way to compare distributions, and python tools (or Mathematica 11) to fit the curve and obtain the derivative for each point.

- which model do you suggest to describe distribution of observed values for similarity between objects in a weighted network (here, a collaborative knowledge base is represented as a weighted network, where weight is the similarity value of two given articles - should I expect an exponential? a poissonian ? why ?)
- how to compute curve fit and extract derivative of the curve at a given point (python or Mathematica 11)

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Working with Mathematica, suppose you data is in the list `data`. Then if you want to find the cubic polynomial that best fits your data, use the [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html) function:

```
Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x]
```

In general the usage for the `Fit` command looks like

```
Fit["data set", "list of functions", "independent variable"]
```

where Mathematica tries to fit a linear combination of the functions in that list to your data set. I'm not sure what to say about what sort of curve we would *expect* this data to be best modeled by, but just remember that any smooth function can be approximated to arbitrary precision by a polynomial with sufficiently many terms. So if you have the computational power to spare, just let your list of functions be a long list of powers of `x`. Although it does look like you have an asymptote at `x=0`, so maybe allow there to be a `1/x` term in there to capture that. And then of course you can use [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot) to plot your curve on top of your data to compare them visually.

Now to get this best fit curve as a function in Mathematica that you can take a derivative of:

```
f[x_] := Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x]
```

And then the obvious change you are talking about occurs when the second derivative is zero, so to get that `x` value:

```
NSolve[f''[x] == 0, x]
```

Comment: thank you @Mike Pierce! I have an asymptote at x=0 by construction: points on X axis does not represent values, but the sorted _i-_position of a neighbour respect to a parent node (which has position 0). Now, I tried to `Plot[ Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x], {x, xmin, xmax}]` but nothing shows up .. Could explain (or point the theorem - who was, Cauchy? I m rusty in calculus ! :) ) why the obvious change happens when `f'(x)=0`? 
Looking at the first graph, that change is in the first 50 values, a polinomial of x^3 seems not to describe it... You available in chat for helping in modelling?

Comment: The point you are describing is called an [inflection point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html), and they occur when the *second* derivative `f''(x)` equals zero. You can read about that in any calculus textbook. In one terse sentence, inflection points occur when the rate at which the rate of change of your function switches between being positive and negative (your rate of change switches between increasing and decreasing).

Comment: I am looking at the point where the rate of curvature 'significantly' decrease to almost a "linear" shape, not said it will change sign of curvature. The idea is that, on one side, I would like to group type of articles with similar distributions of similar articles (model of the curve), and on the other side, select the most similar articles to a parent by looking at how "close enough" they are to it, respect to the distribution. I updated a new picture to show what I mean: the curves are distributions of similar articles respect to a parent article: I would like to locate that point.